# how to get clientWidth of firstChild

Tags: javascript, css

I want to get client width of firstChild

**Css**

```
.ot{width:100px;height:200px}
```

**JS**

```
var ra = document.getElementsByClassName("r")[0];
var n = ra.firstChild.clientHeight;
var ca = n ;
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="r"><div class="ot"></div></div>
```

want to get the height of `ot` through class `r`, why not `ca` is showing 200

Answer (score 2):

Use `firstElementChild` instead of `firstChild`.

Answer (score 0):

It is working. You can read more about HTML DOM Here. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp

```js
var ra = document.getElementsByClassName("r")[0];
var n = ra.firstChild.clientHeight;
var ca = n ;

alert(ca);
```

```css
.ot{width:100px;height:200px}
```

```html
<div class="r"><div class="ot"></div></div>
```

Comment: w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FATMX1JOJKP1 undefined

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this toy your code, should show a current height of desired `div`:

HTML:

```
<p id="demo"></p>`
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function myFunction() {
var ra = document.getElementsByClassName("r")[0];
var n = ra.firstChild.clientHeight;

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;

}
```

CSS:

```
.ot{width:100px;height:200px}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the working snippet, i have modified your code , just Run this snippet , you can check with your first child height and width

```js
var ra = document.getElementsByClassName('r')[0];
var n = ra.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
alert( 'width is =' + n.clientWidth + ' , and height = ' + n.clientHeight );
```

```css
.ot{
   width:100px;
   height:200px 
}
```

```html
<div class="r">
   <div class="ot"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you run this snippet ?

Comment: did you see this  
w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FATMX1JOJKP1

Comment: yes i did , i think we can select the first child but the  clientWidth can't get that way. is my answer is working for you ?